# Updating tracker variables inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to keep track of a complex set of variables and update them, from within a dictionary. If a dictionary is not the appropriate tool here, please let me know.

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
dict = {a: [(b, c)]}    # {1: [(1, 1)]}
a = 1
b = 1
c = 2
dict = {a: [(b, c)]}    # {1: [(1, 2)]}
a = 1
b = 2
c = 1
dict = {a: [(b, c), (b, c)]}    # {1: [(1, 2), (2, 1)]}
a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
dict =    # {1: [(1, 2), (2, 1)], 2: [(1, 1)]}
a = 1
b = 1
c += 1
dict =    # {1: [(1, 3), (2, 1)], 2: [(1, 1)]}
```

Please note this is not viable Python code, just an example of the four procedures that I'm trying to keep track of. If a changes, I want a new key, if b changes I want a new pair of values in the appropriate key of a, and if c changes, I want to update the existing pair of a: (b, c).

Couple more examples given the existing dictionary:

```
a = 2
b = 4
c = 1
dict =    # {1: [(1, 3), (2, 1)], 2: [(1, 1), (4, 1)]}
a = 6
b = 3
c = 1
dict =    # {1: [(1, 3), (2, 1)], 2: [(1, 1), (4, 1)], 6: [(3, 1)]}
```

My question is basically I have no idea how to syntax for:

- the process of updating the values of c, or if it is even possible.
- adding new pairs of (b, c) to existing keys without replacing the existing pairs

Okay, someone asked to see what I've tried.. so I can do the first one obviously.
    dict[a] = [(b, c)]

if b changes, I don't know how to add it to the existing key without replacing the existing pair of [(b, c)]
if c changes, I don't know how to perform arithmetic on the value inside the pair inside the key.
Sorry, I'm fairly new, I know this is probably just a syntax question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason not to use a `dict` of `dict`s, e.g.:

```
>>> d = {1: {1: 1}}
>>> d[1][1] = 2
>>> d
{1: {1: 2}}
>>> d[1][2] = 1
>>> d
{1: {1: 2, 2: 1}}
```

Comment: Yeah this could probably work quite well, let me try him out. Thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and it was very easy to convert the dictionary back into a list of tuples for the exact output I wanted. Thanks!